# TensorFlow Optimization in DSVM

Tags: azure, docker, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

**Problem statement first:** How does one properly setup tensorflow for running on a DSVM using a [remote Docker environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/experimentation-service-configuration#running-a-script-on-a-remote-docker)? Can this be done in `aml_config/*.runconfig`?

I receive the following message and I would like to be able to utilize the increased speeds of the extended FMA operations.

> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

**Background:** I utilize a local docker environment managed through Azure ML Workbench for initial testing and code validation so that I'm not running an expensive DSVM constantly. Once I assess that my code is to my liking, I then run it on a remote docker instance on an [Azure DSVM](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu).

I want a consistent conda environment across my compute environments, so this works out extremely well. However, I cannot figure out how to control the tensorflow build to optimize for the hardware at hand (i.e. my local docker on macOS vs. remote docker on Ubuntu DSVM)

Answer (score 0):

The notification is indicating that you should compile TensorFlow from the source to leverage this particular CPU architecture, so it runs faster. You can safely ignore this If you choose to compile, though, you can compile and install the TensorFlow source code, and then use the native VM execution mode (vs. using Docker) to run it from Azure Machine Learning.

Hope this helps,
   Serina